# Need to convert all page of a website as pdf

Tags: node.js, pdf

I want to download the documentation as pdf of a tool/library like `express.js`.So how can I do this?
Please help me giving some suggestion of tools library to make this happened.I know some **node.js** stuff

Comment: It is off-topic to ask for library recommendations on Stack Overflow.  Also, you didn't give your approach or anything you tried.  At the moment it sounds like you could just visit the page and print to PDF using your browser.  This question mostly needs focus, but is showing a few reasons to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar approach in one of my applications, and i used puppteter for it, you can see the example of a pdf download in its documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer

The code for using it is quite simple, just go to the desired url and set the pdf name you want for it and the format.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://news.ycombinator.com', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
  });
  await page.pdf({ path: 'hn.pdf', format: 'a4' });

  await browser.close();
})();
```